# transfering files android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to transfer files between 2 android mobiles.

This is sender

```
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String ipaddress , filepath;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ipaddress =params[0];
        filepath=params[1];
        try {
            File file  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),filepath);

            Socket socket = new Socket(ipaddress,5321);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);


            long length = file.length();
            dos.writeLong(length);


            String name = file.getName();
            dos.writeUTF(name);


            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            int theByte = 0;
            while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(theByte);
            bis.close();
            dos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is receiver code :

```
   @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(5321);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "waiting for connecting ..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            while (true){
                mysocket = ss.accept();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connected:" + massage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(mysocket.getInputStream());
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
                long fileLength = dis.readLong();
                String fileName = dis.readUTF();
                String downloadfolderpath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath();
                File files = new File(downloadfolderpath + "/" + fileName);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(files);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                for(int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) bos.write(bis.read());

                bos.close();
                dis.close();



            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

AND THIS CODE TO GET FILE PATH (NOT SURE ABOUT THE RESULT OF IT)

```
Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT >>
AND ON ACTIVITY RESULT I GET THIS VALUE
intent.putExtra("filename", data.getData().getPath());
```

Any help

Comment: Can you clarify what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: not transfering the file even if i stATIC THE PATH AND THE NAME OF THE FILE and i sent the utf successfuly alone not all .. if i know the wrong in the code then i can fix it alone but  dedicate the problem is a problem it self becouse i run the apk on phone